# Better alternative to multiple checks for typeof for nested dom object properties

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

I often find that to avoid undefined errors on dom stuff I have to do something like this:

```
if("undefined" != typeof parent 
    && "undefined" != typeof parent.main 
    && "undefined" != typeof parent.main.location){
// Act on a current iframe page from that page's parent location
}
```

Otherwise there's the potential to just get an undefined error when working with such heavily nested dom objects.  Is there an easier way to check for these nested object properties without breaking everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to be (and shouldn't be in this case) so specific with your checks.

Just do this:

```
if(parent && parent.main && parent.main.location) {
```

---

Your original code would still fail when looking for a property  on a `null` value. This handles that case, and in a shorter way.

You can change the last check to be more specific if need be, but the ones before it simply need to do a "truthy" test since you're ultimately just checking for an object.

Aside from that, you could make a function that'll shorten this a little. Up to you if it's worth it.

```
function getNested(obj) {
    for (var i = 1; obj && i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        obj = obj[arguments[i]]
    }
    return obj;
}
```

---

```
getNested(parent, "main", "location");
```

---

Another alternate is this:

```
if(((parent || {}).main || {}).location) {
```

If there's ever a falsey value returned, the `|| {}` will substitute an object, avoiding the error.

Comment: Weird, I don't get why the first suggestion works, but it does seem to.  I would have thought that parent or any one of the other object properties would have simply thrown an undefined error just like using them without them being present does.  Anyway, works for me, thanks.

Comment: @Kzqai: You're welcome. It works because the `&&` operator short-circuits when it knows it will fail. So the first "falsey" value causes it to return that value immediately and not evaluate the rest.

Comment: Well, I'm familiar with the fact that the && short circuits, but I don't get why any of the variables would ever be `false` in the line of tests, as opposed to just being `undefined`, and thus causing the same problem as using `parent.main.location without` checking that it exists.  Still, it works, so I'll just re-examine the approach some day if I come across circumstances that it doesn't work for.

Comment: @cookiemonster your function can works to check this? this.props.myState.form[nameForm].values[inputName]